# How to skip query validation for an expected invalid query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm interacting with a service from a big firm where the API's URL is something like this:

```
https://provider.com/api/loans:search
```

due to how [Ruby validates URIs](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_1_378/URI/Generic/check_query) I keep getting this error

```
URI::InvalidURIError: query conflicts with opaque
from /Users/luiz/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/generic.rb:832:in `query='
```

Other URLs from this provider are also like this but they have prefixes like `something/else:transactions` and I don't get this error.

Contact them and ask to update the URL is out of the question.

Is there a way to somehow skip query validation? Or update the query in a way that the call would still work and validations would be happy with it?

I haven't tried anything because I don't even know where to start

Comment: Are you certain the https:// is being included when it tries to validate it/

Comment: @SaraTibbetts yes, I double-checked and triple-checked it. To make sure that it wasn't the https, I changed the URL to `loans/search` just to try and the validation passed so I'm sure it is this `:`

Comment: Can you try with ruby version 2.6.5 or 2.6.6? I only tested the first one and I didn't get this error. I think it could be [this change](https://github.com/ruby/uri/commit/4fe23ecd85ca74c96147eac47af50f6b160f9453#diff-1213c2ff0540b083e465bd3c54e104c642a9347598998245c2696ec8404359de)

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using? The link you're using is to APIDock (which is a spammy garbage site) for Ruby 1.9.1 which was EOL a loooong time ago.

Comment: sorry for the link, I didn't know that. I'm using Ruby 2.7.1 @HubertJakubiak

Comment: also @max I'm using 2.7.1

Comment: MRI 2.7.1 has no problems in parsing that uri. I think you'll have to dig into the stack trace and figure out whats actually going on here. I would really help us help you if you edit the question to provide as much context as possible.

Comment: I would add debugger in `uri` library and find exactly the place when it raises an error.

Comment: I will try to do that @max and Hubert, thanks for the help so far!